70s movie where fatally ill wife is frozen to be thawed when her illness is cured
There was a movie (released around 70s or early 80s I think) where someone's wife was fatally ill. She was frozen to be kept alive, until a cure is available.
Much later, a cure was found, and she was thawed and cured. But the world had changed too much for her to live easily.
There's a famous quote which I think was from this movie: "Today is the first day of the rest of your life".

Gonna need more detail than that if possible. This is pretty vague on all points.

Yes, it could be improved, but at least it contains year, genre, a very distinct premise, plot details & a possible quote.

Possibly the drama Live Again, Die Again from 1974 with Donna Mills and Vera Miles about a husband freezing his terminally ill wife to be cured in the future and the complications that arise. From IMDb:

After being cryogenically frozen for more than 30 years, a woman wakes to find her husband an old man and her children older than she is. She also wakes to find that her daughter is crazy and wants her dead. 

Here are the film's first few minutes:




It is the 1975 Spanish movie Un Largo Retorno (aka A Long Return). Link to the movie 
1. In Spanish - 


2. In English - 


